# How to perform sum and avg on few columns in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

foo, foo_bar are expressed as ActiveModel classes

```
create table foo (id, captured_date)
create table foo_bars (id, foo_id, val1, val2)

insert into foo (1, '2012-11-01')
insert into foo (2, '2012-11-02')

insert into foo_bars (1, 1, 1, 1)
insert into foo_bars (1, 1, 2, 2)
insert into foo_bars (1, 2, 3, 3)
insert into foo_bars (1, 2, 4, 4)
```

I am expected to show the following in a table (date, sum(val1), avg(val2))

```
2012-11-01 3 1.5
2012-11-02 7 3.5
_________________
           10 2.5
_________________
```

The above is sum(val1), avg(val2) across dates

What would be the easiest way to achieve this using AR queries in your view. How should my view code look like and what queries should I use.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
select("date, SUM(val1) as sum_val1").group("date").pluck(:date, :sum_val1)
```

You will get an array of the sums only. You can add fields as you wish.
The solution the other guy mentioned is not as good because it does the sum in Ruby not in SQL.
To display it's really simple, it's just an array! Display <%= result.inspect %> and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**for sum**

```
FooBar.sum(:val1)
```

or if you want to pass condition

```
FooBar.where("foo_id = ? ", foo_id).sum(:val1)
```

or if you have a object in `view` then you can do

*for example*

```
@foobars.sum(:val1)
```

**for avarage**

```
FooBar.average(:val1)
```

Comment: How do I go about constructing the table in my view. The table gets constructed for multiple dates and the the cumulative sum/avg is applied. When you do FooBar.where(...).sum(:val1), how do I get the values and also apply to the view. For simplicity sake, I added two values, but I have many of them.

Comment: what you want to display?  for display sum you can write @foo.foobars.sum(:val1). val1 is your field in table

Comment: Each row in the table is a sum and avg, you have given just a mechanism to do this overall. How should create my view code, so that I can render this effectively for all dates. I am assuming multiple queries needs to be fired here.